# adding additional information to the auth session in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I used the laravel auth that comes default with laravel 5.3. What i'm wondering is how can i add additional information to the session on a successful login? So that I can fetch the information i need with

```
$user = Auth::user()->someField
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do it via the User object returned by Auth::user()? Why not use Session facade directly?

Comment: how would i do that once a user logs? where would i put that?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the **Session** facade directly instead of accessing it via the **User** object.

In order to get what you need, you'll need to hook into Laravel's event system.

First of all, you need to define a listener that will be triggered when user authenticates and will put all necessary data in session:

```
<?php namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Session;

class AddDataToUserSession
{
  public function handle(Login $loginEvent)
  {
    Session::put('key', 'some value you want to store in session for that user');

    // you can access the User object with $loginEvent->user
    Session::put('user_email', $loginEvent->user->email);
  }
}
```

Then you need to register this listener so that it's triggered when user logs in. You can do that in your **EventServiceProvider** class. You'll need to add your listener to the list of listeners triggered on login event:

```
protected $listen = [
  'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
    'App\Listeners\AddDataToUserSession',
  ],
];
```

Comment: thanks i did that but nothing is getting stored in the session. the session doesnt even exist. i even added teh provider info